# How to cache the js files?

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, caching, cookies

I wanted to cache my all js files using .htaccess file and I have tried the following code but I don't know why it is not working. Please let me know what kind of mistake am I doing or is it possible to create cache of js file using .htaccess file.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public" 
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>
```

or --------

```
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
   </filesmatch>
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi Sree, Thanks for reply, I tried this but not working. To tell that I have removed all content from htaccess file and add only your code but still not working. Is there anything am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from html5 boilerplate's server config. You can take the full set from https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess
That will include for all mime types, i just included for js here

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
   # JavaScript
    AddType application/javascript                      js
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

    # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Thanks for reply, I tried this but not working. To tell that I have removed all content from htaccess file and add only your code but still not working. Is there anything am I missing?

Comment: check if the mod_expires and mod_mime module is actually installed/enabled in apache